# SQL - OleDbCommand not updating DB

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, ole

I am using an OleBdCommand To Insert A record into a Db, but the update never persists.

Here is the Code

```
    public void InsertCandidate(XElement element, ref OleDbDataAdapter adapter, OleDbConnection sqlConnStr)
    {
        if (sqlConnStr.State == ConnectionState.Broken || sqlConnStr.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlConnStr.Open();

        try
        {
            string query = "Insert Into Candidate Values(@priKey, @Name, @LName, @Phone, @Add)";
            OleDbCommand InsertCandidate = new OleDbCommand(query, sqlConnStr);
            InsertCandidate.Parameters.AddWithValue("priKey", element.Attribute("CAND_NUM").Value);
            InsertCandidate.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", element.Attribute("CAND_FNAME").Value);
            InsertCandidate.Parameters.AddWithValue("LName", element.Attribute("CAND_LNAME").Value);
            InsertCandidate.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", element.Attribute("CAND_PHONE").Value);
            InsertCandidate.Parameters.AddWithValue("Add", element.Attribute("CAND_ADDRESS").Value);
            InsertCandidate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A Error occured whilst trying to execute the command.\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

NO exceptions, errors or anomalies are generated!

Any Advice

M

---

I even tried this.

```
            //InsertCandidate.ExecuteNonQuery();
            adapter.InsertCommand = InsertCandidate;
            adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

***Thanks Every One ***

Aiden's Code Worked, but i should have read Tony's Post Better hence i accepted his answer (he said it first)

Kind Regards

And Thanks Once Again!

Comment: Do you get any error messages or exceptions thrown? Some more information than "the update never persists" would be useful.

Comment: Try `MessageBox.Show(InsertCandidate.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());` to see if you get zero or one.

Comment: @LarsTech i get 1 - What does this mean. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Markus - use a MessageBox to display the result of the ExecuteNonQuery method, it may give some more information about the problem.

Comment: @Tony - LarsTech also suggested that - and i did . Ps it returns 1 and i am trying to figure out what it means. Am i correct in saying it returns the number of rows affected! If that is the case then why is it not showing in the Database

Comment: It means it worked.  Make sure you are looking in the correct database for your results.  It can get confusing when you have Visual Studio "attach" your database.

Comment: This is getting to me - I have done as you suggested and still it does not appear in either. I renamed the original one (the one not "attached" by VS) and opened in Ms Access The one from the Project, but to no avail.!

Comment: Problem is hard to see from our end obviously.  Try `MessageBox.Show(sqlConnStr.DataSource);` to see the value of your database in your current connection string.

Comment: @LarsTech - Lars and Tony Thanks for all your help.

anyway Lars: The Result is `|DataDirectory|\Placement.accdb` which is obviously the one VS copies to the Project Directory

Comment: Obviously do a search on your computer for `Placement.accdb`.  One of the ones you find will have your inserted info.

Comment: @LarsTech - I did, and still there is not one database with the inserted info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you executed your SQL statement in isolation from your code to make sure it works?

As you have not posted the table definition it could be because you are not specifying the fields in your `insert` statement.

I'm not an OLEDB expert but all the examples I can find on the net use question marks in place of parameters. Try the SQL statement like this:

```
string query = "Insert Into Candidate Values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

**Update**

Looking at the documentation for the OleDBCommand it will only throw an `InvalidOperationException` and not an `OleDbException` in the event of an error. You should add this exception handler and see if that gives you any more information.

Alternatively change your exception hanndler to catch the generic `Exception` type to see if you even get an exception.

Comment: Sorry and Yes i have - It Works Fine but i don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Yea i also got an article like that from MSDN - they say you can't have named parameters, yet i know this not to be the case!

Thanks but that doesn't work either

Comment: Thanks i added the Exception as InvalidOperationException and still no errors

Comment: @Markus - The only other thing I can think of is if you are using transactions on your DB connection. It's hard to say if this is the case as you have only shown the method which is passed the connection. Can you clarify if you are starting a transaction before passing the connection to the method?

Comment: I must confess that i don't quite understand but - if i remove the test to see whether or not the connection is open, it always throws an exception because at that point the connection is still closed!

Answer (score 1):

```
            string query = "Insert Into Candidate Values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            OleDbCommand InsertCandidate = new OleDbCommand(query, sqlConnStr);
            InsertCandidate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", element.Attribute("CAND_NUM").Value);
            InsertCandidate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", element.Attribute("CAND_FNAME").Value);
            InsertCandidate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", element.Attribute("CAND_LNAME").Value);
            InsertCandidate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", element.Attribute("CAND_PHONE").Value);
            InsertCandidate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", element.Attribute("CAND_ADDRESS").Value);
            //InsertCandidate.ExecuteNonQuery();
            adapter.InsertCommand = InsertCandidate;
            adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

this will work!